# Symmetric Positive Definite 2x2 matrix equal to an Upper Triangular * Transpose of Upper Triangular

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a symmetric positive definite matrix $$ B = \begin{bmatrix}
41 & 12 \\ 
12 & 34
\end{bmatrix}$$

I am trying to find an upper triangular matrix $U$ such that $B = U^t U$

$\lambda_1 = 25  \lambda_2 = 50$   with  $v =  \begin{bmatrix}
0.6 & -0.6 \\ 
-0.8 & -0.8
\end{bmatrix}$

In solving for the upper triangular matrix $U$, I tried to solve for $$  \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\ 
0 & c
\end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 \\ 
b & c
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
0.6  \\ 
-0.8
\end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}
15  \\ 
20
\end{bmatrix}$$

This reduces to the system:

$$ 6/10 a^2+b^2 - 8/10 bc = 15$$
$$6/10 bc - 8/10 c^2 = 20$$

Does anyone have any suggestions for a better approach?

Comment: Arthur, I think I have tried this before, please see above, but it creates a nasty system of equations.  Is that what you were suggesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $$U = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{pmatrix}$$ We can compute the product $$U^t U = \begin{pmatrix} a^2 & ab \\ ab & b^2 + c^2 \end{pmatrix}$$ The rest should be simple: one solution is $$a = \sqrt{41}, b = \sqrt{\frac{144}{41}}, c = \sqrt{34 - \frac{144}{41}}$$